# How to find out If user has made any changes in row inside table. Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have table code look like this.

---

```
   <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <table>  
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Date Published</th>
        </tr>

        <td>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Author) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Author) %>
</td>
<td>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePublished) %> 
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DatePublished) %>
</td></table> 
 <input type="submit" value="Create" />

 <% } %>
```

Inside Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
}
```

If user change value in table how to track which row value has been changed.

thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your example only displays one row but if you have many rows there should be some identifier drawn but I cannot see any parameter that could be used to identify a given Book object except for Title which as a plain string is not very good.

Comment: Actually i forgot to add For loop in my code. But, if There is a multiple row and column then how should i find out in controller which row user has made changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your controller, query the DB to get the old values and check each row to see if it was changed. I can't imagine any other (secure) option.

If you're trying to make your view tell your controller which row was changed, I would say to you that this is not the best solution since some users could intercept the request and change the values before it reaches the server.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model class something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    private string title;
    private string author;
    private DateTime datePublished;
    private bool isModified = false;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; isModified = true; }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get { return author; }
        set { author = value; isModified = true; }
    }

    public DateTime DatePublished
    {
        get { return datePublished; }
        set { datePublished = value; isModified = true; }
    }

    public bool IsModified
    {
        get { return isModified; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i used this code in my program but Modified is not working. When ever i change date modified should be changed true to false but it's not working. Thanks for your Help..